# How can I sort price string in ElasticSearch?

Tags: node.js, sorting, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

In my example i tried to sort but i have no success. My problem is because my price is string and the price is like that => 1.300,00. When I sort string price i have that for exemplo. 0,00 | 1,00 | 1.000,00 | 2,00.
I wanna format format in double for sort or like similar that.
How can i do that ?
[image: output]

Comment: You can reindex the data with correct mapping using reindex API or you can have the price field indexed as both integer and text.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to keep `Price` as a keyword in Elastic search best approach would be to map `price` as `scaled float` in elastic search like this:

**New Mapping:**

```
PUT [index_name]/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "price2": {
      "type": "scaled_float",
        "scaling_factor": 100
    }
  }
}
```

To solve your problem you can add new mapping and convert your value from `string` to `numeric` value:

**Update by query:**

```
POST [index_name]/_update_by_query
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }, 
    "script": {
       "source": "ctx._source['price2'] = ctx._source['price'].replace(',','')"
    }
}
```

This query will convert your `keyword` value to `string` and map it in another field named `price2`, then you will need to have an `ingest pipeline` to do the process to new entries:

**Ingest pipeline:**

```
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
  "pipeline": {
    "processors": [
      {
        "script": {
          "description": "Extract 'tags' from 'env' field",
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": "ctx['price2'] = ctx['price'].replace(',','')"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {
      "_source": {
        "price": "5,000.00"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You need to remove `_simulate` and add this `ingest pipeline` to your index.

Comment: `query:{ multi_match:{
query: `${search.trim().toLowerCase()}`,
type: "best_fields",
analyzer: "standard",
 fields: [ "nome^30","categoria^15","sub_categoria","caracteristicas.cor","caracteristicas.Marca","caracteristicas.Produto","caracteristicas.Modelo"],
                                    tie_breaker: 0.3,
                                    auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query: true,
                                    fuzziness: "AUTO"
                                }
}`

Comment: Thank you, but i have no idea how to repair that. I wanna sort this price.